# GTM: How to track Blog Users that land on product pages?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a website with product pages (`https://www.mywebsite.example`) and a blog, all in the same domain (`https://www.mywebsite.example/blog`).

I would like to track all users that started a session on the blog and landed on product pages (let's say non-blog pages).

I have been trying to work with a GA Event Tag triggered by 2 trigger:

1. All Element Trigger with Click URL not containing blog
2. Just Link Trigger with Click URL not containing blog

Plus an Exception/Blocker Page View Trigger with Path not containing blog.

It doesn't work. I am a newbie in using GTM. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enhanced ecommerce on your website you could filter those sessions with a segment within Google Analytics.

[image]